# Getting SQL login failed error (18456) when connecting to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am trying to connect to an Azure SQL database using SSMS. I know the credentials are correct but I keep getting the error message

> Login failed for user xxxxxx

I am using SQL Server authentication and I have already added my client IP address to the server in Azure.

Comment: In SSMS on the "Connect to Server" dialog, click Options, then under the "Connection Properties" tab enter the database name in "Connect to database".    Give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is an SQL server error, so your login request is reaching the database. It is therefore not a network problem.

There is therefore something wrong with the user account or related configuration. Things it could be:

- SQL Server account authentication is not turned on (Only AD authentication by default)
- The user is configured with a default database, that he does not have access to

Comment: turns out I made a silly mistake with the credential. So the problem had to do with incorrect password